# Movie about a man who goes to prison for shooting one of his family's murderers

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this American movie on TV 1 or 2 years ago. I got halfway through then the recording stopped. A brief description follows:

A family orders Pizza for home delivery. The doorbell rings. The wife thinks it's the pizza delivery. She opens the door. Thugs burst in, rape and murder the wife and daughter. The husband arrives home and finds his family murdered. The thugs are arrested. There is a court case but they get off on a technicality. The thug steps outside of court and walks down the steps. The husband, waiting outside, snatches a gun from a policeman and shoots the thug dead. The husband is then arrested, put on trial and sent to prison for murder. In prison he befriends others who devise a breakout. A group of prisoners escape on a work bus, kill the driver and eventually escape by train.

That's as far as I can remember. Please help with the title or name of actors in movie.

Comment: Just a few questions:

- Do you remember if the family lived in a house or apartment?
- Was the daughter a young child, teenager, or just younger than the mother? 
 - Were the criminals and victims all of the same ethnicity?

Comment: @user5281 Some similarities with [A Man Apart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Man_Apart)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds a bit like *[Law Abiding Citizen](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1197624/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl)*, which came out in 2009. The film includes a man whose wife and daughter are raped and murdered, one of the thugs gets off light with a plea deal, and the man exacts his revenge on both thugs. He ends up in prison, where he tunnels out...

The trailer is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJlTR-Cygcw).

Comment: I thought that at first but none of the second half fits at all.

Comment: I also thought this at first, but is not how the movie tracks at all. In [Law Abiding Citizen](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1197624/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl), the Clyde is hit and is unable to respond while watching his family being murdered. The bad guys are put on trial, subsequently get off of (well, one of them does) charges, and thus begins the plotting/planning of Clyde. Great movie in my eyes. Gerard Butler does the part justice. The character's interaction with Nick Rice (Jamie Foxx) is really good as well.